# angular2 how to use complex observable without duplicate subscription

Tags: angular, observable

I have a class Page(definition below) and service which returns an observable Page. How do I use the observable properly without duplicate subscriptions. Plunker(not working) http://plnkr.co/edit/8xwclHsGm2jKdW9A0fZ4?p=preview

```
export class Page<T>{
  content: Array<T> = new Array();
  last: boolean = true;
  totalPages: number = 0;
  totalElements: number = 0;
  size: number = 0;
  number: number = 0; // Page number
  first: boolean = true;
  numberOfElements: number = 0; //Number of elements in current page
}


export class DataGridService {
  getPageForGrid(gridName:string):Observable<Page<any>>{
    return anObservable; //code removed. see plunker
  }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'data-grid',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li>Page size: {{page.size}}</li>
    <li>Number: {{page.number}}</li>
    <li>Total pages: {{page.totalPages</li>
    <li>Total Elements: {{page.totalElements}}</li>
    <li>Number of elements:{{page.numberOfElements}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#row of page.content; #i = index">
          <td>{{row['column1']}}</td>
          <td>{{row['column2']}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>`,
providers:[DataGridService]
})
export class DataGridComponent {
  @Input gridName: string;

  page: Observable<Page<any>>;

  constructor(){
    this.dataGridService = new DataGridService();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes){
    this.page = this.dataGridService.getPageForGrid(this.gridName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code, you can see [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTUdH0?p=preview).

As you can see here, `Observable` isn't complex at all and it doesn't care what type of data it emits. It can be simple string, data object (like in your case) or anything else really.

I'd recommend you use `Observable` as a generator, like I did with `Observable.of()` and don't make it with `new Observable()`, at least until you really understand how it works...

```
@Injectable()
export class DataGridService {
  getPageForGrid(gridName:string):Observable<Page<any>>{
  var page = new Page();
      page.size = 2;
      page.totalPages = 10;
      page.totalElements=19;
      page.numberOfElements=2;
      page.content = [{column1:"11", column2:"12"},{column1:"21", column2:"22"}];

    return Observable.of(page));
  }
}

@Component(...)
export class DataGridComponent {
  constructor(public dataGridService: DataGridService){
    this.dataGridService.getPageForGrid(this.gridName)
      .subscribe(page => this.page = page);
  }
}
```

Comment: This code I think no longer using page in DataGridComponent as observable. The 'page' now look like a plain instance of Page<T>. See the modified code as plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/G5iiwV?p=preview which does not work because the ChangeDetectionStrategy is Push. If you remove 'changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush' from the component definition then it will work. But I want OnPush to work.